# Please change month number to month name in https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

Tags: feature-request, users-page, dates

In https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators, the dates of appointment are mentioned like this:

> appointed 6/15/2021

I was kinda confused about the date format as my country follows DD/MM/YYYY.

It would be great if it could be changed to something like this:

> appointed Jun 15, 2021

Changing the way how date is displayed in the website will make it consistent with how dates appear on the rest of the site.

Comment: If this is somehow not feasible, YYYY-MM-DD (2021-06-15) is less ambiguous.

Comment: @Someone no. SE already use a very specific format, really no need to use other formats. Making things consistent is very hard, but also very important.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I guess SE does use the format mentioned by Someone. You can check it in timeline of posts by pressing "toggle format". Anyway, I would prefer the format suggested by me in the post instead of the one suggested by Someone.